# jQuery ajax base auth working only from external websites but not from local request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authorization

This code works when used on external websites (e.g. jsfiddle.net)

but not when used on my website itself:

```
var $ = jQuery;

var makeBaseAuth = function(user, pswd){ 
    var token = user + ":" + pswd;
    var hash = "";
    if (btoa) {
        hash = btoa(token);
    }
    return "Basic " + hash;
};

var settings = {
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://mywebsite.org/wp-json/wp/v2/settings",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "authorization": makeBaseAuth("admin", "mypassword")
    }
}

$.ajax(settings)
.done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
})
.error(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

I get this error

> responseText: "{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"You do not have permissions to do it.","data":{"status":401}}"
>
> statusText: "Unauthorized"

I've tried to use `"crossDomain": false` but without success...

Why it's not working? How can I make it working also from local request?

---

**Update:** Thanks to your suggestions I solved by adding this header:

```
"X-WP-NONCE": "<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ); ?>"
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: What is the log you are getting

Comment: What is `btoa`?

Comment: @AjAX. is base64 encoding function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: @charlietfl Ah, thanks.

Comment: Add an error handler!! Also inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Not enough debugging information given

Comment: How can it anyway work on JSFiddle. With `Same-Origin-Policy` in place.

Comment: if you access the website through www.mywebsite.org the url aslo should start with `www`

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to use the wp nonce when making local request. Again... use debugging tools...error handler & dev tools network

Comment: @charlietfl I added the error handler and updated the post, please have a look. The error is "Unauthorized, not enough permissions"

Comment: Read up on needing to use nonce instead of basic auth on local page. Not 100% sure but think it is required

Comment: @charlietfl I solved it! Thanks! It indeed needed a nonce. See updated post